# Handling loop with nodejs asynchronous callback

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I'm new to nodejs and mongoose.
I have a database dated from 2009 until now and would like to count number of data of each month, 
and return as json array. Slow async callback results all dates as Aug. 1, 2014

What is the proper way to implement this?

```
var dbURL = 'mongodb://localhost/database';
var db = require('mongoose').connect(dbURL);
var c_db = require('./models/models.js').c_db;

var start_date = new Date(2009,0,1);
end_date = new Date(2014,8,1),
next_date = new Date();

var test_json=[];

var total_months = (end_date.getFullYear() - start_date.getFullYear())*12 + (end_date.getMonth() - start_date.getMonth());

var next_date = start_date;

for(var i=0;i<total_months;i++){

  var firstDay = new Date(next_date.getFullYear(), next_date.getMonth(), 1);
  var lastDay = new Date(next_date.getFullYear(), next_date.getMonth() + 1, 0);
  next_date.setDate(lastDay.getDate()+1);

  c_db.count({'shipdate':{'$gte':new Date(firstDay),'$lte':new Date(lastDay)}},function(err,query){

    var item = {
      "Date": firstDay,
      "Count": query
    }
    test_json.push(item);
  });

}

setTimeout(function(){
  console.log(test_json);
},5000);
```

Comment: `c_db.count({'shipdate':{'$gte':new Date(firstDay),'$lte':new Date(lastDay)}},function(err,query){` why are you doing `new Date(firstDay)`? Are those not already date objects?

Comment: firstDay and lastDay were hardcoded at the beginning, thx for mentioning :)

Comment: I guess you could define a callback function, `whenFinished`, that's called when `test_json.length === i - 1`. Because of closures, if you put this after `test_json.push(item)`, it'll call it, even if the for loop has finished looping. So something like `if (condition) whenFinished()` on the line after `test_json.push` should work.

Answer (score 1):

Be careful when you are writing javascript with async callbacks. What you want to do is to continue to the next item in the loop when the current async is finished. You can use a the "async" module: https://github.com/caolan/async

```
var async = require("async");
var dbURL = 'mongodb://localhost/database';
var db = require('mongoose').connect(dbURL);
var c_db = require('./models/models.js').c_db;

var start_date = new Date(2009,0,1);
end_date = new Date(2014,8,1),
next_date = new Date();

var test_json=[];

var total_months = (end_date.getFullYear() - start_date.getFullYear())*12 + (end_date.getMonth() - start_date.getMonth());

var next_date = start_date;

async.timesSeries(total_months, function(n, next) {
  var firstDay = new Date(next_date.getFullYear(), next_date.getMonth(), 1);
  var lastDay = new Date(next_date.getFullYear(), next_date.getMonth() + 1, 0);
  next_date.setDate(lastDay.getDate()+1);

  c_db.count({'shipdate':{'$gte':new Date(firstDay),'$lte':new Date(lastDay)}},function(err,query){

    var item = {
      "Date": firstDay,
      "Count": query
    }
    test_json.push(item);
    next();
  });
}, function(e) {
  console.log(test_json);
});
```